# Running fiji/imagej macro from terminal

Tags: imagej

I have made a macro in fiji/imagej that i would like to activate via the terminal in a shell script. As it now stands, the macro does not need any inputs, I just want to make fiji run the macro when activated from the terminal, and save its output in the output folder. The script for the macro looks like this:

```
input =  "/Users/matsboh/Documents/PhD/Experiment/Image analyses/Raw/";
output =  "/Users/matsboh/Documents/PhD/Experiment/Image analyses/Results/";

setBatchMode(true); 
list = getFileList(input);
for (i = 1; i == list.length; i++){

var im = i;

name = "raw_" + im + ".jpg"; 
dir_name = input + name;

open(dir_name);


run("Subtract Background...", "rolling=50 light");
run("8-bit");

run("Make Binary");

name = "results_" + im + ".csv"; 
dir_name = output + name;

run("Analyze Particles...", "size=100-20000 show=Nothing display clear");
saveAs("Measurements", dir_name); 
close();

}
```

If this is possible, how would i precede?

Cheers,

Mats

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On OS X:

```
/Applications/Fiji.app/Contents/MacOS/ImageJ-macosx --headless -macro myAwesomeMacro.ijm
```

On Windows:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Fiji.app\ImageJ-win64.exe --headless -macro myAwesomeMacro.ijm
```

On Linux:

```
~/Fiji.app/ImageJ-linux64 --headless -macro myAwesomeMacro.ijm
```

Personally, I like to alias the full path to my ImageJ installation's launcher to either `imagej` or `fiji` so I can then just type:

```
imagej --headless -macro myAwesomeMacro.ijm
```

Of course, how you do that aliasing will also depend on your OS.

See the [Headless](http://imagej.net/Headless) page of the ImageJ wiki for further details on running macros and scripts from the console.

Comment: I wrote the same command but I have this problem ** Bad type on operand stack**
and I spend many hours to solve it but it didn't work

Comment: @Mariam AL-Kassar You can ask for help on the [ImageJ Forum](http://forum.imagej.net/) after reading the article on [writing good bug reports](http://imagej.net/Bug_reporting_best_practices).